# Check the determinant of a matrix given a parameter

Tags: matrices

- How do I calculate the determinant of the following matrix?
- And for which values of m is the determinant non null?

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & m & 3 \\
4 & m^2 & 9
\end{bmatrix}
I have tried the

> co-factoring method

and what I got was `m(m+1) + 6`
I'm trying to figure what would be the right way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What's the co-factoring method?

Comment: This is when you multiply each element in any row or column by its co factor

Comment: Oh! Usually, it's called a Laplace expansion along a row or a column.

Comment: $m=2$ or $n=3$, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can calculate the determinant of any 3x3 matrix with the method described in the introductory section of the corresponding [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant).

After you have successfully calculated the determinant (-m^2 + 5 m - 6), determine the zeros of this [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) depending on `m`. Except for these two values of `m` the determinant will be non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *Vandermonde determinant*

*Hint*: subtract the first column from the other two.

Comment: What do I do after that ?

Comment: Expand the detyerminant along the 1st row. It amounts to calculating a $2\times2$ determinant.